# Trying to make a recursive function that returns all combinations of an input array. I keep getting a Type Error 'cannot read properties of undefied'

Tags: javascript, recursion, typeerror, combinations

I am stumped as to why I am getting the error because I am passing in an array that is defined and should have length. Yet, I keep getting the "Type Error on line XXX: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

Here is the code I am working on...

```
function getAllCombos(arr) {
    // declare an array to hold results
  let results = [];
  // declare an innerfunction which takes a prefix and the original array passed in
  function recurse(prefix, arr) { 
    // loop through the original array, our base case will be when the loop ends
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    // push the results of spreading the prefix into an array along with the current element both in an array
    results.push([...prefix, arr[i]]);
    // recursive case: now we build the prefix, we recurse and pass into our prefix parameter an array consisting of the prefix spread in, the current element being iterated on, and the original array sliced after our current element
    recurse([...prefix, arr[i], arr.slice(i+1)])
    }
  }
  // call the inner function with an empry prefix argument and the original array
  recurse([], arr);
  // return the results array
  return results;
}
```

and here are some test cases...

```
console.log(getAllCombos(['a', 'b'])); // -> [['a','b'], ['a'], ['b'], []]
console.log(getAllCombos(['a', 'b', 'c']));
// -> [
//   ['a', 'b', 'c'],
//   ['a', 'b'],
//   ['a', 'c'],
//   ['a'],
//   ['b', 'c'],
//   ['b'],
//   ['c'],
//   [],
// ]
```

Can someone please explain to me why I keep getting this error message even though I am passing in an array that has length?

Thank you for any pointers!

Comment: `function recurse(prefix, arr)` takes two parameters, you pass one: `recurse([...prefix, arr[i], arr.slice(i+1)])`

Comment: What can I see is that you have a variable shadowing. `arr` is in upper scope and in `recurse` function as well and in recursion call you never pass upper scope `arr` cause you have defined inner one which is `undefined`.  Do not use the same names. And pass var also

Comment: Thank you! Both of you!

Answer (score 1):

**where you went wrong**

I think you are calling `recurse` wrong -

```js
recurse([...prefix, arr[i], arr.slice(i+1)]) // <- notice `]`
```

Move the `]` to after `arr[i]` -

```js
recurse([...prefix, arr[i]], arr.slice(i+1))
```

**a fresh start**

That said, I think everything can be improved with use of a simpler function -

```js
function* combinations(t) {
  if (t.length == 0) return yield []
  for (const combo of combinations(t.slice(1))) {
    yield [ t[0], ...combo ]
    yield combo
  }
}

// array
for (const combo of combinations(["a", "b"]))
  console.log(`(${combo.join(",")})`)
  
// or even strings
for (const combo of combinations("abc"))
  console.log(`(${combo.join(",")})`)
```

```
(a,b)
(b)
(a)
()
```

```
(a,b,c)
(b,c)
(a,c)
(c)
(a,b)
(b)
(a)
()
```

**some optimization**

Above `.slice` is effective but does create some unnecessary intermediate values. We could use an index, `i`, like you did in your original program -

```js
function combinations(t) {
  function* generate(i) {
    if (i >= t.length) return yield []
    for (const combo of generate(i + 1)) {
      yield [ t[i], ...combo ]
      yield combo
    }
  }
  return generate(0)
}

for (const combo of combinations(["","","",""]))
  console.log(combo.join(""))
```

To collect all values from a generator into an array, use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) -

```js
const allCombos = Array.from(combinations(...))
```

- To computed fixed-size combinations, *n choose k*, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53464291/633183)
- To compute permutations using a similar technique, see [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66130419/633183)

**without generators**

The chief advantage of using generators for combinatorics problems is each result is offered lazily and computation can be stopped/resumed at any time. Sometimes however you may want all of the results. In such a case, we can skip using a generator and eagerly compute an array containing each possible combination -

```js
const combinations = t =>
  t.length == 0
    ? [[]]
    : combinations(t.slice(1)).flatMap(c => [[t[0],...c], c])
  
const result =
  combinations(["a", "b", "c"])
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

```js
[["a","b","c"],["b","c"],["a","c"],["c"],["a","b"],["b"],["a"],[]]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks... I really need to look into 'yield' and 'generate'. I've never even heard of the last one... Thank you! This taught me so much! The first solution you provided is so mind-bending to me... How did you learn to think like that?

Comment: it wasn't until i carefully read [sicp](https://sarabander.github.io/sicp/) that programming started to make sense to me and i could think and "see" things in new ways. i didn't say so explicitly, but we used _inductive reasoning_ to build programs in this post. I have many answers [about recursion and inductive thinking](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+%5Brecursion%5D+inductive) and many others on the [topic of generators](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+%5Bjavascript%5D+generator). if you have any other questions, i'm happy to assist :D

Comment: i should also mention _sicp_ contains accompanying [video lectures](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/) provided by MIT. do _not_ skip these under any circumstances.