# Writing an n choose k function using recursion: returning the value and number of recursive calls made as a tuple

Tags: python, recursion

I need to define this function `n_choose_k(n,k)` which returns the value of n choose k and number of recursive calls made as a tuple, while keeping in mind the following:

The number of recursive calls should not include the initial function call.

the function returns (-1,0) if:

- k is negative
- n is negative
- n is less than k

Here is what I have so far:

```
def n_choose_k(n, k):
    if k == 0 or k == n:
        return 1,0
    
    elif n < k or k < 0 or n < 0:
        return -1,0
    
    return n_choose_k(n-1,k) + n_choose_k(n-1, k-1)


    >>> print(n_choose_k(5,2))
    (10, 18) ---> Expected
    (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0) ---> Getting
```

Comment: What does the 18 do? If you just do `print(sum(n_choose_k(5,2)))` then you get 5 choose 2 which is 10.

Comment: 18 is the number of recursive calls made. The function returns the value of n choose k and number of recursive calls made as a tuple

Comment: i think you will find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53464291/633183) helpful. let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: In that case you could just do something like `a=n_choose_k(5,2)` and then `print(sum(a), len(a)-2` (see Kevin's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your issues are with the lines `return 1,0` and `return n_choose_k(n-1,k) + n_choose_k(n-1, k-1)`. Python lists (in this case you can think of them as such) get appended when you added them. For example

```
>>> [1,2,3] + [3,4]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

So in this case, all of your `1,0`'s are being added together. (If you exclude the initial function call values, 2, from the total number of inputs, 20, you should get the desired 18 as the number of recursive calls).

I expect you were thinking this happens in Python.

```
# INCORRECT, FALSE Python
>>> [1,2,3] + [3,4,5]
[4,6,8]
```

If you're using Numpy arrays, this can work

```
# With Numpy
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([1,2,3]) + np.array([3,4,5])
np.array([4,6,8])
```

So you have options, either modify your code such that your recursion doesn't append lists or use Numpy.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! However, I'm not sure how I can modify the code so it actually returns the value and the number of recursive calls

Comment: I don't want to give too much away, since I presume this is an assignment. One option is to have a helper function and to pass a counter from function to function. This could keep track of the number of recursive calls and you can return the value at the same time.